# Copy function parameter to const local variable

Tags: c++, performance, glm-math

I'm digging in glm library, and found this type of code, also there are some other simmilar stuff. My question is: what is a purpose to copy function parameter to const local variable inside function, like this -- *T const a(angle)*. Is it for some performance benefits?

```
template<typename T, qualifier Q>
GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER qua<T, Q> angleAxis(T const& angle, vec<3, T, Q> const& v)
{
    T const a(angle);
    T const s = glm::sin(a * static_cast<T>(0.5));

    return qua<T, Q>(glm::cos(a * static_cast<T>(0.5)), v * s);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no purpose.

This was probably done in a misguided attempt to avoid the indirection of repeatedly accessing `angle` (which, being a reference, is probably implemented by the compiler as a pointer). Whether this outweighs the cost of a copy is not obvious: if the type `T` is small and [trivially copyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable) then making a copy is free but for larger types this will in fact incur a nontrivial overhead. On the other hand, the repeated pointer access can often be avoided entirely by the compiler.

Regardless of these considerations, *if* that optimisation was the purpose, it would have been more appropriate to pass `angle` by value instead: first passing by reference and then copying locally truly serves no purpose.

Comment: its type is a template parameter, and probably the code was written before universal references (C++11), when it was quite tricky to efficiently pass such arguments

Comment: @AndriyTylychko Sure, but the point of this answer is unrelated to universal references. If you need a copy, pass by value. This was always true.